# Intellitrace not available for VS 2012 Professional edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellitrace

If so, how do i turn it on? I don't see it under Tools-> Options

If not, anywhere I can download it?

Comment: I posted a related question here: [How possibly did IntelliTrace become available on my Visual Studio Professional installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25537040/450913)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the product matrix from the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare) site.

[image]

It shows that it is only available for the Ultimate edition.

Are you sure your coworker has it on Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Intellitrace is not available in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional version, intellitrace is available in Visual Studio Ultimate edition only.

Comment: that is odd. My co worker is running VS2012 Professional. He has IntelliTrace enabled

Comment: As product matrix shared below by Walt, its clear it's supported in VS Ultimate edition only. I think you are mistaking something other for intellitrace. What exactly your coworker is able to do what you can't with VS Professional edition?

Comment: I have Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3) with IntelliTrace. I don't know how it got there but it shows up in Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) and is enabled from **View -> Toolbars -> IntelliTrace**. I told my colleague to use it and he didn't have it on his VS Pro!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have Intellitrace in Visual Studio 2013 Professional, because there is a bug in Visual Studio licencing system. It happen in some circumstances.