# How can I log my SQL calls in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I used to have it working great. I would just select the output window and all the calls would be logged and output. But then I reinstalled VS 2013 and now I see nothing.

Please note this is a built in feature. Not something I used to do with debug calls or anything in my code.

I have been doing this for over a year now and just cannot figure out what option I selected to make it happen. Can anyone remember how to do this?

Comment: @Samantha/Alan - Are these SQL calls sent through Entity Framework or all SQL calls regardless of how they were sent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with EF 6.0 you would do

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 
    // Other code here... 
}
```

From here: [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For VS2013 Pro, I can't get the query to the output window, but you can make it log to the Message pane of the query results.  Is this what you're referring to?

```
Tools >
   Options > 
       SQL Server Tools > 
           Transact-SQL-Editor > 
               Query Results > 
                   Results to Grid
```

Check 'Include the query in the result set'[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about IntelliTrace?
However it is only available in VS Ultimate editions. See [Intellitrace not available for VS 2012 Professional edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153023/intellitrace-not-available-for-vs-2012-professional-edition)

Comment: No, I'm talking about the SQL calls that I for sooo long made appear in the output window. I am using VS2013 Ultimate btw

Comment: Usually the output in the Output Window is printed with Debug.Write or Debug.WriteLine. Make sure you are running the project in Debug mode.

Comment: There's a way to have this done for you. Just cannot remember what option I used. Never needed to do any Debug.Write or anything like that.